# Build failed with an exception - unity Adds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a simple game, and for the test I decided to add an advertisement there. Until the moment of importing the package with ads, everything was compiled fine, but after that the compiler started giving errors. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class DrwLog : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pnel;
    public GameObject[] ColorButtons;
    public GameObject button;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (Advertisement.isSupported)
        {
            Advertisement.Initialize("*******", false );
        }
        Invoke("Bn", 10f);
        pnel.active = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void Clicked(bool on)
    {
        if (on)
        {
            button.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
        else
        {
            button.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
        }
    }
    public void ColorChnge(int clr)
    {
        button.GetComponent<Image>().color = ColorButtons[clr].GetComponent<Image>().color;
    }
    public void PnelEnble()
    {
        if (!pnel.active)
        {
            pnel.active = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pnel.active = false;
        }
    }
    public void Bn()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
            Advertisement.Show("bn");
        }
    }
}
```

Unity Monetization - full Add-On name.
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]